Why don't aircraft use D.C generators?
I need to research DC generators in aviation, but the only information I can find is about AC being converted to DC. This information is not exactly what I’m looking for.
The only information I could find is that DC generators were used in older or vintage aircraft and have been replaced for reasons of optimization and weight. However, this information wasn’t very clear, so I'm wondering if there are any modern aircraft that uses DC?

I talked with a pilot once who replaced his DC generators with alternators.  He said with the DC generators, he would have to run his engine at ~1500 RPM at night to just get a little light and to power one comm and nav radio.  Once he converted to alternators, he could run all his electronics with the engine at idle.  The DC generators don't output a lot of power with the engines at idle but do a decent job with full power.  He said the alternator weighed a bit more but was well worth the compromise.

For an interesting read Santiago, read up on why trains use DC or in some cases AC. Very interesting!

The HondaJet HA-420 and Embraer Phenom 100/300 use DC starter generators - https://www.ametekpds.com/products/power-generation/dc-brush-starter-generator

Short answer
When large mechanical powers are required, AC motors are used, it's not particular to aircraft. The limiting factor of DC motors is the commutator ring. When AC motors are used, AC sources are required.  Note this is 3-phase AC, using three phases (over two or over DC) helps simplifying motors: 3-phase motors have a predetermined direction of rotation; they can start without assistance.
Motors and generators are similar devices used in reverse, in one case a current creates a magnetic flux, in the other case a magnetic flux creates a current. The pros and cons of generators and motors are mostly the same, in particular DC generators also need a commutator ring; They have the same power limitation. So the most effective combination is AC generator and AC motor.
AC generators are usually driven by the engines, which rotation rate changes with thrust demand. For a long time the problem has been to stabilize the frequency of the generator using mechanical systems. However today the frequency is no more a problem, we have efficient inverters to electronically stabilize it, so AC generators are also used for small power needs.
I'm detailing the DC motor limitation below, but for your research you may be interested also in these questions:

What is the typical voltage and frequency of the electrical generator in an airliner?

How much electrical power does one generator produce on a large turbofan?

How does the A350/380 operate on Variable Frequency AC generators?


AC generators are called alternators, DC generators are called dynamos. Dynamos have been replaced by alternators on cars a long time ago. As commented, dynamos don't deliver much current at low speed: We needed to run the engine at a high rpm to actually load the battery on a car with a dynamo. Alternators can load a battery with the engine at idle speed.
Details follow.



Need to invert pole polarity in motors
Motors are based on how two magnetic poles interact: Poles of the same polarity are pushed away, poles of different polarities are attracted.
In a DC motor:

There is a stator, it can be made of permanent magnets or windings. For simplification let's use one permanent magnet with two poles N and S (or two magnets oriented such as the inner poles are respectively N and S)

There is a rotor made of solenoids (windings) within the stator. Let's use a single solenoid. A solenoid fed with DC current behaves like a permanent magnet, creating two magnetic poles N and S. The poles are reverted, becoming S and N, if the direction of the current is reverted.

(Source)

Magnetic attraction is used to rotate the rotor solenoid until its poles are aligned with stator poles of opposite polarities. When the poles are aligned they keep their position due to attraction, the rotor stops rotating.


To unlock the rotor, the polarity of either the rotor or the stator is inverted, this changes the attraction into a repulsive force moving the rotor poles towards the next stator poles, where they are locked again. The polarity is inverted again and the cycle repeats.
Commutator ring
Inversion is done by a ring and two brushes connected to the DC source. The ring rotates with the rotor, it has segments connected to the rotor pole solenoids. The brushes deliver the current to the segments.

(Source)
As the ring rotates, the segments are in contact with each brush alternatively, the solenoid polarity is constantly inverted.
As the power of the motor increases, the current in the ring segments also increases. But the contact surface between the brushes and the ring segments cannot be increased past a limit, the ring temperature increases with power due to impedance. Wear is stronger, maintenance is required more often.
In addition:

The number of poles is usually large in order to smooth the rotation, meaning the number of segments required is large, and their size smaller, further limiting the maximum current.

Sparks are created between brushes and segments. The effects of the sparks increase with current.


Use AC to remove the commutator ring
The other solution is to change the current direction by directly using AC (AC motors have also other advantages). The inverter is not required anymore.
Advantage of AC generators
Larger aircraft uses AC generators which are more simple and more robust. The frequency is 400 Hz instead of 50 Hz for different reasons, it is mostly historical, and linked to the need to have constant speed drives. With the development of efficient current inverters, the need for constant speed has been removed. One advantage is a higher frequency reduces the size of the voltage transformers since the maximum flux the core can transfer is proportional to frequency.
The 400 Hz frequency was selected by US military long ago as a tradeoff between feasibility of constant speed drives given the engine speed ranges at this time and the corresponding weight reduction (generators, transformers, motors, actuators and wiring, as a higher frequency also requires wires with a larger cross-section due to the skin effect).
Most recent aircraft actually generate AC with a variable frequency, depending on the engine speed. This current can be efficiently rectified, and converted back to AC with the desired frequency, e.g. 400 Hz.
Both AC and DC are present on a large aircraft, but the generators are AC (except the batteries of course). Smaller aircraft which don't require large electrical sources may still have DC generators with a more limited power.

If I may add to "a higher frequency reduces the size of the voltage transformers since the maximum flux the core can transfer is proportional to frequency," this is a huge advantage because using a transformer to increase voltage and decrease current means you can use thinner wires to carry the same power.  This means less weight.  DC-DC transformers are much more complicated beasts, especially high power ones.

@CortAmmon: But the most frequent case in an aircraft is to use transformers to decrease the voltage, not to increase it. The transformer is smaller because of the frequency allowing a smaller core for a given power, whatever the voltage.

@CortAmmon Planes are so small, that voltage step-up is not needed. The main power loss, maintenance and reliability issue are the mechanical constant-speed drives. The 787 generates variable-frequency AC in the engines, about 1/3 of the power is consumed as variable-frequency AC, but the largest motor loads, 1/2 the power, draw from a 270 VDC bus; essentially a split-VFD topology. The A380 and A350 utilize a distributed architecture, where all the AC loads get variable-frequency power.

DC generators aren't widely used in general:

the brush of a DC generator isn't very durable, reliable, and it sparks.

most generators have the rotor inside the stator, so the rotor is naturally smaller than the stator. And between the magnets and the coil, the magnets are smaller. As a result, generators in general have rotating magnets and stationary coils. This structure is impossible for a DC generator, but:

it's easy to convert AC to DC with a rectifier.


In other words, even though there are brushless DC motors, they are in fact AC motors with a built-in VVVF (Variable Voltage Variable Frequency) drive. Same to brushless DC generators: they are in fact AC generators with a built-in AC-DC rectifier.

DC generators were useful for many purposes in an era when mechanical commutation was more efficient than any available form of electronic rectification.  Even if one sets aside reliability issues, mechanical commutation is often less efficient than modern electronic rectification.  The only applications where I could see a DC generator as being useful would be those where one would want the polarity of the current to be controlled by motor direction, and even those could probably still be better handled electronically.
